# date range in Mysql (between)

Tags: mysql

I want to get all the values in the database where date is between two given parameters. Following is my code. Here Date is $date1' and '$date2 are the given parameters.

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM model WHERE  Date BETWEEN('$date1' AND '$date2')");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
        $d=$row['Date'];

            echo $d;


    }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your syntax.  Remove the parentheses after `between`:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM model WHERE  Date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' ");
```

I'm guessing this is your question.